# iPhone touchesBegian not working on iPad, x and y always a zero

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a dual app and copied the block of code for touchesBegan from the iPhone code to the iPad.  I did not make any changes and the method always gives me a zero for x and y for the first touch.

The code block:

```
-(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {

  int iCardId;

  NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

  // we are dealing with one finger get first touch

  // get first touch
  UITouch *touch=[[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

  // get the x and y
  CGPoint pt    = [touch locationInView: self.view];
  float x=pt.x; // this is always a zero
  float y=pt.y; // this is always a zero
  .........
  .........
  .........
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always seen that the correct way to get a `UITouch` is with `[touches anyObject]`. Try that and see if you still get `(0,0)`.

***Edit/Update***

I set up a new single view application and placed the following code into the `UIViewController`:

```
-(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    // we are dealing with one finger get first touch
    // get first touch
    UITouch *touch=[[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the x and y
    CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:[self view]];
    NSLog(@"(%f,%f)", pt.x, pt.y);
}
```

It appears to give me coordinates appropriately. Where did you put your code?

Comment: Hi,Was it for a iPad? The code works on the iPhone, and I copied it to iPad, in which it does not work,